# setTimeout - follow up question

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

I am trying to get javascript setTimeout function working with callback, but getting "missing formal parameter" error from func function...

```
       var pCodes = [ 'a','b','c' ];

    $.each(pCodes, function(index, pCode) {         
        setTimeout(function() { 
            func(pCode, callback); 
        }, 2000);
    });

    function func(in, callback){        
        callback(in);
    }

    function callback(value) {
        alert(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think `in` is as allowed variable name. I think its a reserved keyword